# Dropdownlist not giving selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I had this aspx source code

```
<tr>
            <td>MatchName</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMatchName" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Winning Team</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWinningTeam" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Score</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtScore" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save"  OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

C# Code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string queryMatchDetail = "select MatchId,MatchName from ADMMasterMatch order by MatchDate";
        ddlMatchName.DataSource = clsNewSqlFunctions.GetSelectedData(queryMatchDetail);
        ddlMatchName.DataTextField = "MatchName";
        ddlMatchName.DataValueField = "MatchId";
        ddlMatchName.DataBind();

        string queryTeamDetail = "SELECT [TeamId],[TeamName] FROM [AdmCurrentEventMasterTeam] order by TeamName";
        ddlWinningTeam.DataSource = clsNewSqlFunctions.GetSelectedData(queryTeamDetail);
        ddlWinningTeam.DataTextField = "TeamName";
        //ddlWinningTeam.DataValueField = "TeamId";
        ddlWinningTeam.DataBind();

    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = ddlMatchName.SelectedIndex;
        string query = "UPDATE [ADMMasterMatch] SET Winner = '" + ddlWinningTeam.SelectedItem.Text + "' , Score = '" + txtScore.Text + "' Where MatchId ='" + ddlMatchName.SelectedItem.Text +"'";
        clsNewSqlFunctions.ExecuteQuery(query);
    }
    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("ADMCurrentEventMatchResult.aspx");
    }
```

Here `clsNewSqlFunctions.ExecuteQuery()` and  clsNewSqlFunctions.GetSelectedData() are method to execute query and select data which return data in form of dataset

on `Save_Click` event i am updating data on database from selected value of dropdown list but it is not showing me selected value
It always show value at index 0. on **SelectedText,SelectedItem**
please help me what is wrong with my code

Comment: It's because you re-bind your list on the postback - look up the page lifecycle and the `IsPostBack` property.

Comment: Your `btnSave_Click` query is ripe for a sql injection attack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DropDownList lose index after PostBack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742605/dropdownlist-lose-index-after-postback)

Comment: @DaveParsons what does it mean and how could i correct it

Comment: @Co.Aden: It means a malicious user can "inject" a sql statement which will be run on your DB. `Parameterised queries` or `stored procedures` are the ways to mitigate this risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please bind your dropdown in `!ispostback`

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(!ispostback)
      {
        string queryMatchDetail = "select MatchId,MatchName from ADMMasterMatch order by MatchDate";
        ddlMatchName.DataSource = clsNewSqlFunctions.GetSelectedData(queryMatchDetail);
        ddlMatchName.DataTextField = "MatchName";
        ddlMatchName.DataValueField = "MatchId";
        ddlMatchName.DataBind();

        string queryTeamDetail = "SELECT [TeamId],[TeamName] FROM [AdmCurrentEventMasterTeam] order by TeamName";
        ddlWinningTeam.DataSource = clsNewSqlFunctions.GetSelectedData(queryTeamDetail);
        ddlWinningTeam.DataTextField = "TeamName";
        //ddlWinningTeam.DataValueField = "TeamId";
        ddlWinningTeam.DataBind();
      }

    }
```

When you click a button page again postbacks and which will result in binding the dropdown again..So you will get the selected value as the first index of the dropdown..